# Cocoa application won't run because Contents/MacOS/Application is not a Unix Executable

Tags: xcode, permissions, chmod

My application runs fine on my system, and also on several others.

However, some people can't run the application because the file in /Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName is not a Unix executable file.

Inputting the following line in the terminal forces the application to be executable, and solves the problem:

```
chmod +x ApplicationName
```

Obviously this is a very hacky way around the problem, and I don't want to tell users to enter chmod to run my application. What am I doing wrong? Why is it appearing as a Unix executable file on some systems, but not others? It could be a permissions issue...

Comment: How did they install the application? Do you ship it as a DMG?

Comment: nope, i just give them the .app 

should i always ship as a dmg? can i then run a script to set all my unix executables to +x?

Comment: How do you transfer the .app? Putting it into a dmg or even a zip will preserve permissions. Just copying it onto a DOS-formatted USB stick will probably not.

Comment: at the moment, i transfer the app via dropbox to a client, then he uploads it to a website. so I will try the process using a zip file!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> at the moment, i transfer the app via dropbox to a client

Dropbox has problems with OS X metadata and permissions. Archive the application first (from the Finder context menu) and put the zip file into Dropbox.

Comment: thank you very, very much! zipping the application retained all my file permissions, and solved my problem. thank you!